# Sharing Setting among System Administrator

Tags: administration, appexchange

I am using enterprise edition of Salesforce account and I am one of the admin among 6 admins.
    I have installed an custom app from appexchange but I want to hide the visibility of that app even from other admins. Please let me know the steps if I can do that.

Comment: You cannot do this with standard System Admin profile. You have to assign different profile for other admins.

Comment: Does the App requires a license? Apps that require licenses won't give you access to the App if your user has not been assigned a license, even if the profile has access to the App.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible with standart same administrator profile, the profile have to have view all access.

But you can clone administrator profile and uncheck view all access. Then with sharing rules, you can limit new cloned system administrator profile.